# Populate PHP associative array using loop with mysql data

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm creating simple PHP for output data to apexcharts javascript charts. To make apexcharts usable output I need to provide x and y value of the graphs as JSON. below code, I wrote to output the expected JSON.

```
$data_arr = array();

    global $mysqli_conn;
    $result = $mysqli_conn->query("sql");
    $sql_out = array();
    $sql_out = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows < 1){
            echo "zero";
        }else{
            foreach($sql_out as $item) {
                $data_arr['x'][] = $item['time'];
                $data_arr['y'][] = $item['status_code'];
            }
        }



$test_arr = array(
    array(
        "name"=>"lock",
        "data"=>array($data_arr),
    )
);

echo json_encode($test_arr);
```

my expected json output is like below

```
[
    {
        "name": "lock",
        "data": [
                    {
                        "x": "2019-05-30 07:53:07",
                        "y": "1470"
                    },
                    {
                        "x": "2019-05-29 07:52:27",
                        "y": "1932"
                    }
                ]
    }
]
```

But when I request data from my code what I'm getting something like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "lock",
        "data": [
            {
                "x": [
                    "2019-05-30 07:53:07",
                    "2019-05-29 07:52:27",
                    "2019-05-26 15:46:56",
                    "2019-05-25 07:39:24"
                ],
                "y": [
                    "1470",
                    "1932",
                    "1940",
                    "1470"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I create my expected JSON result from PHP code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating them on a seprate space. When you declare and push them, put them on one container:

```
foreach ($sql_out as $item) {
    $data_arr[] = array(
        'x' => $item['time'],
        'y' => $item['status_code']
    );
}
```

When you do this:

```
$data_arr['x'][] = $item['time'];
$data_arr['y'][] = $item['status_code'];
```

They are on a separate containers, x and y containers, therefore you get the wrong format, like the one you showed.

When you declare them as:

```
$data_arr[] = array(
    'x' => $item['time'],
    'y' => $item['status_code']
);
```

You're basically tellin to push the whole sub batches but together.